# How can i count total number of nodes in a trie data structure

Tags: java, data-structures, trie

I tried this approach but doesn't work. Please  help me with this

```
static int count=0;

static void insert(String key) {
    int level, length = key.length(), index;
    TrieNode pCrawl = root;

    for (level = 0; level < length; level++) {
       index = key.charAt(level) - 'a';
       if (pCrawl.children[index] == null) {
           pCrawl.children[index] = new TrieNode();
       }

       pCrawl = pCrawl.children[index];
    }

    pCrawl.isEndOfWord = true;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? Do you get an unexpected result?

Comment: You never increase the counter...

Comment: Apart from that, why do yo need to count the nodes in a tree when you insert an element? And why is the `insert(...)`-method static? Do you have exactly one instance of this tree? If so, I would recommend using the [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. The question asks how to count nodes, but you show us an `insert` method that definitely is not at all related to counting. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a global variable count and increment it whenever a new node is created while you are inserting a string. Now you don't have to write separate function to count nodes in tree.

```java
 int count = 0;
 static void insert(String key) {
    int level, length = key.length(), index;
    TrieNode pCrawl = root;
    for (level = 0; level < length; level++) {
       index = key.charAt(level) - 'a';
       if (pCrawl.children[index] == null) {
           pCrawl.children[index] = new TrieNode();
           count++;
       }
       pCrawl = pCrawl.children[index];
    }
    pCrawl.isEndOfWord = true;
}
```